# How to call an action method from my _layout view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an action method that display the latest 5 records inside my application :-

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Technology> LatestAssets()
{
      var tech = repository
                          .LatestTechnology()
                          .OrderByDescending(a => a.TechnologyID).ToList() ;
      return tech;    
}
```

But how I can call this action method when the _layout view is rendered (without having to click on any link), and iterate over it an display the information regarding the latest 5 records ?
my _layout view have the following section to display the latest record info under it:-

```
<li class = "nav-header hidden-tablet"
     style = "background-color:#3E9BD4 ; color:white">Latest Assets
</li>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's an action method? Why is it returning an IEnumerable instead of ActionMethod?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this:

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LatestAssets()
{
    var tech = repository
                        .LatestTechnology()
                        .OrderByDescending(a => a.TechnologyID).ToList();
    return PartialView("_Assets", tech);

}
```

**_Assets(PartialView):**

```
@foreach (var asset in Model)
{
     <li class = "nav-header hidden-tablet"
         style = "background-color:#3E9BD4 ; color:white">@asset
    </li>
}
```

Then you can call it in your layout view with this

**EDIT  :**

**Layout View:**

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("LatestAssets", "ControllerName"); }
```

Comment: A simple solution, suggestion add controller name in `RenderAction`

Comment: Worked a treat for me :) I was going down the path of a much more convoluted solution before I saw this.